# Python: Reading line with 'readline()' function and appending to a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, append, readline

My code:

In my file i have these numbers in a list

charge_account = ['4654145', '9658115', '5658845', '5658045', '6181531', '2134874', '5964554']

I am reading the file with a function, appending it to a list and then returning the list:

```
import os
os.system('cls')

def fileReader():
    contentList = []
    with open('charge_accounts.txt','r') as f:
        line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')

     while line !="":
         line = f.readline().rstrip(' \n')
         contentList.append(line)
     # print(contentList)
     # print(len(contentList))
     #contentList = contentList[:-1]
     print(contentList)
          
return contentList
```

Now my question is, when i read all the file content and append them to my list, i am getting an extra blank string at the end of the list.
output:
['4654145', '9658115', '5658845', '5658045', '6181531', '2134874', '5964554', '']

Now i have solved it by using slicing (as i commented them out) but i still have not figured out why i am getting the ' ' in the end of the list. i tried filtering it out but noting happens. i have checked if it there is an extra line in the end of the file but what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: In a normal document there are a lot of control characters throughout that could be giving you your "blank" entry. \n is one but there are a lot. I would recommend a for loop using `f.readlines()` which might clean up those control characters.

Comment: use `while not line.strip():` or even better: `for line in f: if not f.strip(): continue else: ...`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things. You are reading the file line by line in the while loop. This means that after the last line is read, the while condition is still true so you read an extra line (which is empty) but still added to your list.

But you don't need a while loop: use `lines = f.readlines()`. It will read the whole file in a list, and you almost have the list you are aiming for. Almost, because you need to strip each element:

```
def fileReader():
    with open('charge_accounts.txt','r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return [line.strip() for line in lines]

print(fileReader())
```

Comment: i have read that readlines() is considered inefficient of memory and doesnt scale well with larger amount inputs, and  while loop is considered more efficient to iterate over larger files. is there any way i can still solve this with while loop without slicing  the list ?

Comment: It is true that readlines() loads everything into memory. Most often this is not a problem. Yes of course, if your files are Gigabytes, you can also read them line by line. You can always add an empty line check in your while loop to prevent the last empty line from being handled.

Comment: I  realized two more things: in your current case, you are building a list that has about the size of your file. By using the method I suggested, you'll barely need additional memory. In cases where you do other stuff with very large files, you can iterate over the file object itself (so no while-loop needed): `for line in f: <do something with line>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while line !="":
     contentList.append(line)
     line = f.readline().rstrip(' \n')
     
print(contentList)
```

I realized i had to append the while loop primer into the list which i read before the loop started. content.append(line) had to be the first statement in the while loop. This solves the blank entry in the end of list, which in hindsight i realize means that i skipped the first readline value.