# apend method is not working in python code

Tags: python

Inside the below code, the `append` method is not working, line number is 10

```
while True:
    user_action = input("type add, show,edit,complete or exit:-")
    user_action = user_action.strip()
    match user_action:
        case "add":
            todo = input("Enter a todo:-") + "\n"

            file = open('file.txt', 'r')
            todos = file.readline()
            todos.append(todo)

            file = open('file.txt', 'w')
            file.writelines(todos)


        case "show":
            for index, i in enumerate(todos):
                raw = f"{index + 1}-{i}"
                print (raw)

        case "edit":
            number = int(input("which number of todos you have to edit:-"))
            number = number - 1
            new_todo = input("Enter your new todo:-")
            todos[number] = new_todo

        case "complete":
            number = int(input("which number you want to complete"))
            todos.pop(number - 1)

        case "exit":
            break
print ("Bye!")`
```

Below is the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pravin/Documents/python_app_build_project/section7/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    todos.append(todo)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am trying to save the output inside the file, which is file.txt. The old element should not be overwrite with new element. The old element and new element should be saved in the file.txt - this is what I am expecting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743894/python-reading-line-with-readline-function-and-appending-to-a-list

Comment: Where do you initialize todos?  It seems that you're appending to it before assigning it to the empty list `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readline()` method returns `string` type which does not have `append` method. What you are looking for is `readlines()` method. It returns list and has `append` method.

Comment: Thank you so much readlines() method works.